# Why do they sand pine plywood

Tags: plywood, sanding, veneer

Why is pine plywood known as "sanded"? To my touch, it doesn't feel any more sanded than other species of plywood veneers. And in any case, what would be the benefit of sanding plywood at the factory?

Comment: It's sanded compared to construction grade plywood (such as sheathing or subflooring).

Comment: :) As Eli says, compare to unsanded!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is pine plywood known as "sanded"?

Because it has been sanded.

It does not feel any smoother than other plywoods because other plywoods are also sanded at factory. It is just not specified. As @EliIser says in comments compare to similar plywood unsanded, it is very rough!

*The manufacture of softwood or hardwood plywood consists of nine main processes: log storage, log debarking and bucking, heating the logs, peeling the logs into veneers, drying the veneers, gluing the veneers together, pressing the veneers in a hot press, plywood cutting, **and other finishing processes such as sanding**.*

[Source.](https://www3.epa.gov/ttnchie1/ap42/ch10/final/c10s05.pdf)

*The wet strips of veneer are wound into a roll, while an optical scanner detects any unacceptable defects in the wood. Once dried the veneer is graded and stacked. Selected sections of veneer are glued together. A hot press is used to seal the veneer into one solid piece of plywood, which will be trimmed **and sanded** before being stamped with its appropriate grade.*

[Source.](http://www.madehow.com/Volume-4/Plywood.html)

> And in any case, what would be the benefit of sanding plywood at the factory?

Obviously it is to smooth surface, but it is also for thickness control.

*Once the plywood passes quality control, **it will then be sanded to make sure the surface has a smooth surface and its thickness uniform**. Depending on market specifications, the plywood can either be sanded on the face side or both face and back sides. After sanding, the plywood will then be trimmed to its final size.*

[Source.](https://www.famitchell.com.au/how-is-plywood-made/)